# DDD - Aggregates for read-only

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

If we are working on a sub-domain where we're only dealing with a read-only scenario, meaning that our `entities` and `value objects` will not be changed, does it make sense to create `aggregates` composed by roots and its children or should each entity of this context map to a single `aggregate`?

Imagine that we've entity `A` and entity `B`.

In a context where modifications are made, we create an `aggregate` composed by entity `A` and entity `B`, where `A` is the `aggregate root` (let's say that `B` can't live without `A` and there are some invariants involved).

If we move the same entities to a different context where no modifications are made, does it make sense to keep this `aggregate` or should we create an `aggregate` for entity `A` and a different one for entity `B`?

Answer (score 4):

In 2019, there's fairly large support for the idea that in a read only scenario, you don't bother with the domain model at all.

Just load the data directly into whatever read only data structure makes sense to support the use case.

See also: [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs).

Comment: And those data structures can be filled with behaviours or do they remain anemic models? They could encapsulate some behaviour that can be used for the use case we are trying to solve, meaning that they are still considered "domain models", even though we don't apply the concept of `aggregates`. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Quick note, I'm not talking about the case that we are loading some data to send directly to the client, I'm thinking about a business use case where we still need to apply some logic.

Comment: @PedroFaustino: Nothing prevents you from adding logic to the models, as long as all fields of the model a read-only/final, it has no setters or mutable types on it and all input validation happens in the constructor (since its the only way to create this object). It just isn't strictly DDD (and you don't need to apply DDD in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is if B cant live without A and there are some invariants involved, to me A is an Aggregate root, with B being an entity that belongs to it.

Aggregate roots represent a real world concept and dont just exist for the convenience of modification. In many of our applications, we don't modify state of our aggregate roots once created - i.e. we in effect have immutable aggregate roots. These would have some logic for design by contract checks/invariant checks etc but they are in effect anaemic as there is no "Update" methods due to its immutability. Since the "blue book" was written by Eric Evans, alot of things have changed, e.g. the concept of NoSql database have become very popular, functional programming concepts have become very influential rising to more advanced DDD style architectures being recommended such as CQRS. So for example, rather than doing updates to a database I can append (i.e. insert) instead. This leads to aggregates no longer having to be "updated". This leads to leaner anaemic types but this is what we want in this context. The issue before with anaemic types was that "update logic" for a given type was put elsewhere in the codebase instead of being put into the type itself. However if you do not require "update logic" in the first place then you dont have that problem!

If for example there is an Order with many OrderItems, we would create an Order aggregate root and an OrderItem entity. Its a very important concept to distill your domain to properly identify what are aggregates, entities and value types.

Then creation of domain services, repositories etc just flows naturally. For example, aggregate roots and repositories are 1 to 1 i.e. in the example above we would have an Order repository and not have an OrderItem repository. That way your main domain concepts are spread throughout your code in a predictable and easy to understand way.

Finally, in your specific question I would not treat them as the same entities. In one context, you seem to need modification logic - in the other they you dont - they are separate domain concepts to me.

- In context where modifications are made: A=agg root, B=entity.
- In context without modifications: A=agg root (immutable), B=entity(immutable)

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you. I still have one question regarding aggregate roots and its children: if we have don't need to load all the children's of an aggregate  (we might  just need a specific subset to work with)  should we split this into two aggregates? I'm thinking about the context of scheduling an appointment where we can have a person (root) and its schedules (entity), but we are only going to need to load schedules from today forward. How do we deal with this?

Comment: Btw, if we just need to load some data from the database to display to the user (imagine a lookup with values), should we jump the DDD part and just use a query object + DTOs to go straight to the point?

Comment: In relation to the first comment, I would have two aggregates as they are functionally different. I would name these two aggregates something that would reflect their functional difference too

Comment: In relation to the second comment, absolutely, if your code is really simple skip DDD entirely. DDD has its place, it should never be the cause of an over-engineered project

Comment: But if we create two different aggregates, one for the person entity and another for the schedule entity, how do we ensure invariants on the person aggregate such as one person cannot have two schedules at the same time?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear. You end up with a single aggregate the person being the root and the schedule entity is within this aggregate. However this Person-Schedule aggregate (which will only be loaded as a subset of schedules) is still different to the Person-Schedule aggregate that has all Schedules. It sounds like they represent two different things in your domain, they are the same shape but have different data. One aggregate has all schedules, another only has some - name them differently. Invariant checks are probably different here also. That would be my approach in a DDD style codebase